# Android Map Itemized Overlay

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

In the android developer's webpage there's an example on how to show an alert dialog when the user taps on an item in the map.

What I want to do is show the default bubble the maps App shows when you tap on a POI.

Is there a way to do this? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Here is What i did on my project.. hope this helps you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993679/onclicklistener-for-pushpin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice solution for a balloon-like popup for Google Map markers: 
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You'll have to roll your own views with background ninepatches (or just use a decent looking default system one, like the Toast background drawable), and add a TextView (or whatever View you want) with that background to an overlay. It's a little silly that there's nothing built in for that since the "bubble with a bit of text" is a very common developer need, but it's actually really not that much work.